# Looping through array and printing values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array with the structure

`var citizens1 = [{lat:null,lng:null,socialSecurityNumber:null}];`

I would like to use a loop to print the values of each element however this does not work for me:

**Code**

```
function animate(index,d) {  

       if (d>eol[index]) {

        marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);       

        if(marker[index].getPosition() == endLocation[index].latlng){
            console.log('Completed'+' '+index);
        }  


        return;
     }

         var p = polyline[index].GetPointAtDistance(d);
         marker[index].setPosition(p);
         updatePoly(index,d);

         timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+","+(d+step)+")", tick);

         citizens1.push({lat:marker[index].getPosition().lat(),lng:marker[index].getPosition().lng(),socialSecurityNumber:global_citizens[index].socialSecurityNumber});

         if(citizens1.length = '500'){           
             console.log('500 records saved');          
             window.clearTimeout( timerHandle);

             for(var i = 0; i < citizens1.length ; i++){


                 console.log(citizens1.lat +',' +citizens1.lng+','+citizens1.socialSecurityNumber); 




             }

             citizens1 = [];
         }

  }
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: citizens1[i].lat is undefined
```

Comment: Is the period after `name` a typo just in here, or in your real program as well?

Comment: sorry that was a typo will fix this

Comment: Could you show your full code, or is this it?

Comment: it seems to work, http://jsfiddle.net/KKAg5/

Comment: If this code doesn't work, then it's because you array doesn't contain what you think it does.  I'd suggest you do a `console.log(Students[i])` instead and see what's really there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`citizens1.length = '500'` should be `citizens1.length == 500`

Also

```
console.log(citizens1.lat +',' +citizens1.lng+','+citizens1.socialSecurityNumber);
```

should be

```
console.log(citizens1[i].lat +',' +citizens1[i].lng+','+citizens1[i].socialSecurityNumber);
```

You need to print the properties of each element of the array, not of the array itself.

Comment: i will fix that thank you however it still doesn't fix the printing of each element

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have initialised the Students as

```
Students = [{name:null,age:null,address:null}];
```

Comment: i modified the code posting the real code instead of an example of my scenario

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
console.log(citizens1.lat +',' +citizens1.lng+','+citizens1.socialSecurityNumber);
```

needs to have the array index in it:

```
console.log(citizens1[i].lat +',' +citizens1[i].lng+','+citizens1[i].socialSecurityNumber);
```